# MVC Open binary in Microsoft Word

Tags: google-chrome, model-view-controller, activex, cpu-word

I support a web application on an intranet which has a word icon the user can click which will then retrieve bytes from a SQL server and then open Microsoft Word to display the document.

While this works well, our organisation is moving from IE to Chrome, and this doesn't work in Chrome, and from what I have heard Chrome doesn't support ActiveX which is what is used to open Microsoft Word.

So we are looking for a solution that will work in Chrome.

A quick example of what we do.

Javascript fired by onclick event

```
var wordObject = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");

wordObject.Documents.open('http://localhost:8080/Document/Download/MyDocument.docx?documentId=12345');
wordObject.Visible = true;
```

Action in Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(int documentId)
{
     var result = DocumentService.GetLatestDocumentVersion(documentId);

     if (!result.Succeeded)
     {
          return HttpNotFound();
     }

     return new DocumentResult(result.Data.FileData, result.Data.FileType, result.Data.FullName);
}

public class DocumentResult : FileContentResult
{
    private ContentDisposition _contentDisposition;

    public DocumentResult (byte[] fileContents, FileType fileType, string fileDownloadName)
         : base(fileContents, fileType.ToMimeType())
    {
         string disposition = fileType == FileType.Pdf ? DispositionTypeNames.Inline : DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
         _contentDisposition = new ContentDisposition(disposition);
         _contentDisposition.FileName = fileDownloadName;
    }
}
```

I want the same functionality but in Chrome, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So instead of opening word through javascript you simply replace the url with something like

```
<a href="ms-word:nft|u|https://localhost/Document/Download/MyDocument.docx?documentId=1899240|s|">Document</a>
```

This uses office uri schemas see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Thanks to MS Premier Support.